# jQuery multiselect drop down menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I have a simple html multi select drop down list:

```
<select id="transactionType" multiple="multiple" size="10">
  <option value="ALLOC">ALLOC</option>
  <option value="LOAD1">LOAD1</option>
  <option value="LOAD2">LOAD2</option>
  <!-- etcetera... -->
</select>
```

I want to continue to use this list in the event javascript is disabled however with javaScript I would like to render the list as a multi-select drop down list. That is it only shows one item in the list until clicked and then will expand to show x items and provide scrolling, where I can select multiple elements as you would expect while holding shift or ctrl.

New to jQuery was searching the http://jquery.com/ but haven't yet found what I need.

**Edit** Struts2 users, the selected answer will url encode with [] this causes issues in struts2 the fix however is very easy. Simply open jquery.multiSelect.js and search for "[]" and delete the one instance this is used in a string concatenation. I also am using jQuery 1.4.4 as opposed to the 1.3.2 which came bundled with it and everything works just fine.

Comment: I think you might be looking in the wrong place — that's the right job for a plugin or a jQuery UI widget. http://plugins.jquery.com/ and http://jqueryui.com/ might get you started.

Comment: Just starting jQuery I found all the proposed solutions useful but Bill N solution is very close to what I wanted visually, but really it is even I bit more 'cool' than I wanted (I mean the check boxes, I'd be fine with plain highlighted elements).

Answer (score 91):

**Update (2017):** The following two libraries have now become the most common drop-down libraries used with Javascript. While they are jQuery-native, they have been customized to work with everything from AngularJS 1.x to having custom CSS for Bootstrap. (Chosen JS, the original answer here, seems to have dropped to #3 in popularity.)

- Select2: https://select2.github.io/
- Selectize: http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Obligatory screenshots below.

Select2:
[image: Select2]

Selectize:
[image: Selectize]

---

**Original answer (2012)**: I think that the [Chosen library](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) might also be useful. Its available in jQuery, Prototype and MooTools versions.

Attached is a screenshot of how the multi-select functionality looks in Chosen.

[image: Chosen library]

Comment: Free license and nice features, I like it.

Comment: Bad documentation: any luck on figuring out how to deselect values?

Comment: @imparator: You mean programatically, or from the UI? With the UI, you just need to click the cross icon for the multi-selects.

Comment: on page_load, how can i apply an array to select items in chosen?

Comment: I don't know why but I can not use more than one multi-select on the same page, using select2 (last version, sad..), because a plugin sends with the form only first multi-select values(((. But I need use several multi-select elemnts. I think I do all correct.. may be there is some extra "super" option, that controls a such behavior.

Answer (score 16):

I was also looking for a simple multi select for my company. I wanted something simple, highly customizable and with no big dependencies others than jQuery.

I didn't found one fitting my needs so I decided to code my own.
I use it in production.

Here's some demos and documentation: [loudev.com](http://loudev.com)

If you want to contribute, check the [github repository](http://github.com/lou/multi-select)

Comment: Nice, this is a different approach that I really like.  I'm not sure if we'll use it, but it got me thinking about what I want the UI to really look like.  Thanks!

Comment: @lou I am having a weird experience with your multiselect plugin.. i explained in my question here `-->` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725015/multiselect-js-refresh-after-change .. can you please see if their is something wrong in what i did.

Answer (score 14):

- Download jquery.multiselect
- Include the jquery.multiselect.js and jquery.multiselect.css files

  `<script src="jquery-ui-multiselect-widget-master/src/jquery.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-multiselect-widget-master/jquery.multiselect.css" />`
- Populate your select input
- Add the multiselect

  `$('#' + Field).multiselect({
      checkAllText: "Your text for CheckAll",
      uncheckAllText: "Your text for UncheckCheckAll",
      noneSelectedText: "Your text for NoOptionHasBeenSelected",
      selectedText: "You selected # of #" //The multiselect knows to display the second # as the total
  });`
- You may change the style

  `ui-multiselect { //The button
      background:#fff !important; //background-color wouldn't work here
      text-align: right !important;
  }
  ui-multiselect-header { //The CheckAll/ UncheckAll line)
      background: lightgray !important;
      text-align: right !important;
  }
  ui-multiselect-menu { //The options
      text-align: right !important;
  }`
- If you want to repopulate the select, you must refresh it:

  `$('#' + Field).multiselect('refresh');`
- To get the selected values (comma separated):

  `var SelectedOptions = $('#' + Field).multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
          return this.value;
      }).get();`
- To clear all selected values:

  `$('#' + Field).multiselect("uncheckAll");`

Comment: i am using the same js and css but i am unable to get checked  values can you guide me where i am doing mistake?var SelectedOptions = $('#ddlColumn').multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
                                  return this.value;
                              }).get();
                              alert(SelectedOptions);

Comment: Can you please point to the documentation and options available for this?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [erichynds dropdown multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) with huge amount of settings and tunings.

Comment: I'd like it if the filter would allow me to select the top filtered element with the enter key, maybe it can but the demo didn't show that. This looks interesting and I might want to use it but currently I like that the jQuery MuiltiSelect's simplicity so it is still the winner until select by enter is the default behavior for that widget.

Comment: Also when the filter is active, if the up/down arrows could move into the option list that would be nice too.

Comment: Link is not working

Answer (score 3):

You can use chosen.i download all file from this link
[Chosen download Link](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="prism.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="prism.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

<ion-view view-title="Profile">
<ion-content class="padding">

<div>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <div class="input-label">Enter Your Option</div>
            <select class="chzn-select" multiple="true" name="faculty" style="width:1000px;">
                <option value="Option 2.1">Option 2.1</option>
                <option value="Option 2.2">Option 2.2</option>
                <option value="Option 2.3">Option 2.3</option>
            </select>   
    </label>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All file on all same folder

Comment: Please on page_load, how can i apply an array to select items in chosen?

Comment: Don't understand what u want .if possible ask a question on stackoverflow and share ur question links

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="mycontrolId" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1" >one</option>
   <option value="2" >two</option>
   <option value="3">three</option>
   <option value="4">four</option>
</select>

var data = "1,3,4"; var dataarray = data.split(",");

$("#mycontrolId").val(dataarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hack your own, not relying on jQuery plugins... though you'd need to keep track externally (in JS) of selected items since the transition would remove the selected state info:

```
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('#transactionType').focusin(function(){
        $('#transactionType').attr('multiple', true);
      });
      $('#transactionType').focusout(function(){
        $('#transactionType').attr('multiple', false);
      });
    });>  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="transactionType">
    <option value="ALLOC">ALLOC</option>
    <option value="LOAD1">LOAD1</option>
    <option value="LOAD2">LOAD2</option>
  </select>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery MultiSelect for implementing multiselect drop down menu with checkbox. You can see the implementation guide from here - [Multi-select Dropdown List with Checkbox](http://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/)

Implementation is very simple, need only using the following code.

```
$('#transactionType').multiselect({
    columns: 1,
    placeholder: 'Select Transaction Type'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/robert/xhHkG/

```
$('#transactionType').attr({
    'multiple': true,
    'size' : 10
});
```

Put that in a `$(function() {...})` or some other onload

### Edit

Reread your question, you're not really looking for a multiple select... but a dropdown box that allows you to select multiple. Yeah, probably best to use a plugin for that or write it from the ground up, it's not a "quick answer" type deal though.