# HTML/PHP one line dropdown list multiple selection

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, user-experience

does anyone know a way to create a dropdown list as in a select statement that allows multiple selections but can display on one line. Adding the multiple="multiple" option causes it to display on as many lines as there are options which is not suitable for this project's layout  Css and/or javascript would be fine however, hoping to avoid js frameworks.  Thinking something with onclick event to show the standard multi-line dropdown box might work but not sure how to implement.

Following displays on several lines.

```
 <select name="items[ ]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
     <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option></select>
```

Comment: (Very) similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753407/jquery-multiselect-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [select2](https://select2.github.io/) which gives you an easy possibility to create such a select-box you need.
Example from that page fitting your needs:

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While the op wanted to avoid using js frameworks, this is still the best answer. No sense in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

See [size attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select).

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="1">
```

Comment: When you set size=1, you lose access to the other options, ie you can only see the first one.

Comment: I mis-understood what you were asking then. Check out https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Comment: -1 as this simply doesn't work. I suggest editing your answer to suggest the jquery option instead of just leaving it in a comment.