# loop item list with checkbox in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

previously I was using the list to show as select box.

```
<select name="chosenList">
    <c:forEach>
    ...
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Now I want to show that list with checkbox and data , something like that `<input type="checkbox" /> This is checkbox <br />`. How can I achieve it to loop and show each data with checkbox?

Comment: There is no HTML select box with checkboxes. You can create your own component that *acts* like a select box that includes checkmarks, but no such thing exists in standard HTML.

Comment: I wanted such a thing too. See the selected answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753407/jquery-multiselect-drop-down-menu check out the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Wont work, you can either get rid of the checkbox and use

```
<select multiple>
   <c:forEach>
        <option>press ctrl+lmb</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

of loop the checkbox without select

```
<c:forEach><label><checkbox />clickme</label></c:forEach>
```

Regards