# multiselect.js refresh after change

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, input, multi-select

Just trying to use [multiselect.js](http://loudev.com/) for multiple type select input's

Here is what `select` looks like

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
    <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
</select>
```

Using multiselect like this -

```
var s = $('#my-select');
s.multiSelect({
    selectableHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Options</div>",
    selectionHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Selected</div>"
});
```

Here is what it looks like  `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/6k8gW/5/

[image]

This work's fine until i try to add new option

```
s.append($('<option />').text("new").val("value"));
s.multiSelect('refresh');
```

And the output is like this `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/6k8gW/6/

[image]

Why `refresh` is not working properly ?

Comment: It seems like a bug to me. Also, it seems to me that this thing was not meant to have options appended. Maybe there is a way to avoid dynamic adding of options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed a bug. I submitted a patch today which should fix this.

For your interest if you encounter any problem with my plugin you can add an issue at https://github.com/lou/multi-select/issues

Thanks