# jquery getting each individual value from array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a multiselect dropdown and when the users selects either individual items or by pressing ctrl or shift I would like to capture the items and store them in an array, which afterwards take each value in the array and do some other things with it.  I have accomplished the first part which is this:

```
var selectValues = new Array();
$('#ddlBProduct').change(function () {
    selectValues = [];
    selectValues.push($(this).val());
    MyFunction();
});

function MyFunction(){
    $.each(selectValues, function () {
        var theitem = $('#' + this).html();
   });
}
```

no in that function MyFunction for some reason i keep getting all the values as 1 value instead of each individual on.  What I am assuming is that the "individual" value in the array is actually a list of all of the selected option instead of separating them into the array.  help?

EDIT:  removing the

```
selectValues = [];
```

results in this:

```
["81"] 
["81"] 
["81", "102"] 
["81"] 
["81", "102"] 
["81", "102", "30"]
```

and thats when selecting one option and pressing shift and selecting more items.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753407/jquery-multiselect-drop-down-menu ?

Comment: thanks looks pretty cool but I'd rather not use plugins, it would seem this shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var selectValues = new Array();
$('#ddlBProduct').change(function () {
    selectValues = $(this).val();
    MyFunction();
});

function MyFunction(){
    $.each(selectValues, function(idx, val){
        console.log('value: ', val)
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N5ndZ/)

Comment: and how do i iterate through each one to get each individual value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var selected_options = $(this).parent().find('option:selected');
    myFunction($.map(selected_options, function (selected_option) { return selected_option.value; }));
});

function myFunction(selectValues){
    console.log(selectValues)
    $.each(selectValues, function () {        
        var theitem = $('#' + this).html();
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2kRq/1/)