# HTML: Select multiple as dropdown

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I would like to use a `select` field with `multiple` as a common dropdown field with `size=1`:

```
<select name="test[]" size="1" multiple>
    <option>123
    <option>456
    <option>789
</select>
```

Why doesn't this code show the arrow for the dropdown?

Thanks!

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Use `<option>value</option>`. You are missing the the closing `option` tag.

Answer (score 73):

[A similar question was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19206919/2393763)

If you're able to add an external library to your project, you can try [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Here's a sample:

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple class="chosen-select" name="test">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>American Black Bear</option>
    <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
    <option>Brown Bear</option>
    <option>Giant Panda</option>
    <option>Sloth Bear</option>
    <option>Sun Bear</option>
    <option>Polar Bear</option>
    <option>Spectacled Bear</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

One thing I've run into, you have to include JQuery BEFORE you include Chosen or you'll get errors.

Answer (score 8):

Because you're using multiple. Despite it still technically being a dropdown, it doesn't look or act like a standard dropdown. Rather, it populates a list box and lets them select multiple options.

Size determines how many options appear before they have to click down or up to see the other options.

I have a feeling what you want to achieve is only going to be possible with a JavaScript plugin.

Some examples:

[jQuery multiselect drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753407/jquery-multiselect-drop-down-menu)

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/

Answer (score 8):

It's quite unpractical to make multiple select with size 1. think about it. I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wqd0yd5m/2/

```
<select name="test" multiple>
    <option>123</option>
    <option>456</option>
    <option>789</option>
</select>
```

Try to explore other options such as using checkboxes to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) of `<select>`. You are using 2 attributes:

> **multiple** 
> This Boolean attribute indicates that multiple options can be selected in the list. If it is not specified, then only one option can be selected at a time. ***When multiple is specified, most browsers will show a scrolling list box instead of a single line dropdown***.

> **size** 
> If the control is presented as a scrolling list box (e.g. **when multiple is specified**), this attribute ***represents the number of rows in the list that should be visible at one time***. Browsers are not required to present a select element as a scrolled list box. The default value is 0.

As described in the docs. `<select size="1" multiple>` will render a **List box** only **1 line visible** and a scrollbar. So you are loosing the dropdown/arrow with the `multiple` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to some plugin like [Jquery multiselect](https://ehynds.github.io/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) dropdown.

Also you need to close your option tags like this:

```
<select name="test" multiple>
    <option>123</option>
    <option>456</option>
    <option>789</option>
</select>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ooorht5d/1/)**

Answer (score 6):

Multi-select

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
     var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices-multiple-remove-button', {
        removeItemButton: true,
        maxItemCount:5,
        searchResultLimit:5,
        renderChoiceLimit:5
      }); 
     
     
 });
```

```css
.mt-100{margin-top: 100px}body{background: #00B4DB;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);background: linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);color: #514B64;min-height: 100vh}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.js"></script>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select upto 5 tags" multiple>
            <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
            <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
            <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
            <option value="Bootstrap 3">Bootstrap 3</option>
            <option value="Bootstrap 4">Bootstrap 4</option>
            <option value="Java">Java</option>
            <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
            <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
            <option value="Python">Python</option>
            <option value="Hybris">Hybris</option>
            <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
            <option value="NOSQL">NOSQL</option>
            <option value="NodeJS">NodeJS</option>
        </select> </div>
</div>
```

dropdown menu

Tryout this real example - https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multiselect-dropdown-list-83601849

Answer (score 1):

In Html you have add "multiple" attribute

```
<div id="multy_select_div" class="form-group">
   <label>lebel <small style="color: red">*</small> </label>
   <select  name="lebel" multiple class="form-control" id="multy_select">
        <option  value="" class="text-center" >---Select Item---</option>
        {% for item in queryset%}
            <option value="{{item.id}}">{{ item.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
   </select>
</div>
```

Also you have to add js(select2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectChannel').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#channelDiv')
    });
});
```

Answer (score -19):

```
    <select name="select_box"  multiple>
        <option>123</option>
        <option>456</option>
        <option>789</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: you need to explain the solution and also Your solution nowhere near the answer of this question. -1