# How to Fixed Options in React-Select because in the documentation i dont clearly understand how it workd

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How to make a fixed options in react select i dont seem to understand their documentation on how the thing work

**Here's what i wanted in react-select**

[React-Select Fixed Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r358D.png)

**This is my form with react select i want to fix the CONNECT option i also set the isFixed to false except for the CONNECT options**

[This is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKiLT.png)

**Here's my Code**

*This is my fetched data i also set the isFixed value to false except in CONNECT*

```
async function fetched_roles() {
  const response = await axios.get("/rmsroles");
  let newresponse = response !== null && 
  (response.data).map((role) => (
    role.role == 'CONNECT' ?
    { value : role.role , label : role.role , isFixed: 'true' }
    :
    { value : role.role , label : role.role , isFixed: 'false' }
    ))
  setIsLoading(false);
  setRoles(newresponse);
}
fetched_roles();
 }, []);
```

*This is the react-select component*

```
 <Select
   name="roles"
   onChange={handleGetRoles}
   isMulti
   isLoading={isLoading}
   options={roles}
   components={animatedComponents}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is called multiple select. There is a similar question here:
[HTML: Select multiple as dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190588/html-select-multiple-as-dropdown).

You can also use other library like [React-Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select)

Comment: im using react-select lib but im bit confused in their docu on how fixed options work

Comment: Just check the doc and I found `isClearable={value.some((v) => !v.isFixed)}`. I believe it made all option with isFixed==false clearable. Therefore made those with isFixed==true fixed.

Comment: i also do that but when clearing all the list the connect option will be erased too im setting the connect option isFixed to true