# Implementing another list dropdown upon extra selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mySQL database, and I have the option that it displays all the 'Treatments' as a dropdown box on my html page. 
How would I go about implementing the code, so that if the user wants to select more than one treatment, another dropdown box will appear?

**EDIT:** e.g. Lets say you are shopping for some items online, and you have all the items listen in a dropdown box. You pick one, and then you want to pick more. So you click: 'add more' and another dropdown appears on the page where you can select another item.

Here is the **PHP** code:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'hostname';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());


$query = "SELECT * FROM `Treatments`";

$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$options = "";

if (!$result){
    die("No results found.");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $options .= "<option>$row[1]</option>";
}


?>
```

Comment: *...another dropdown box will appear?* **Question Unclear** Please Elaborate.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at available jquery plugins such as bootstrap-multiselect which will be helpful to you.

Comment: @Kamal is there any way to implement that with a mySQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to make multiselect drop down. 
If you add `multiple = "multiple"` HTML tag then drop down will be used as a multi select.

```
<select name="anyName[]" multiple>
  <?php
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option>$row[1]</option>";
 }
 ?>
</select>
```

For more help you will need to look this link. [jQuery multiselect drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753407/jquery-multiselect-drop-down-menu)

Hope It will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Ahh I see thank you! I just didn't know if there is a way to approach this problem. I will try it out :)

Comment: One suggestion : `name="anyName"` should be `name="anyName[]"` as selection is multiple.

Comment: Yes I think, now you need to try. I have edited little answer and given link.