# Is there any way to use checkbox in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use `checkbox` in `dropdownlist` so we can check multiple value from it and later we can use that `checkbox` value. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What about using a `ListBox` with `SelectionMode="Multiple"`?

Comment: @Pikoh No there are data like Person Name come from database, so i don't think so listbox can help with that.

Comment: I've never seen a drop down list of checkboxes. I can't see that this would have any use

Comment: @JeremyKern , I want to select multiple person name at once from dropdownlist later i can use it or process it. So i wonder if there is a way something like this.

Comment: I don't get what the problem of data coming from database is with using a `ListBox`...maybe you could explain it

Comment: @Pikoh I agree that listbox can do help with multiple selection option but with amount of data listbox will be lenghty. So thats why i say no to listbox, but if there is any way to handle this problem in listbox then i will appreciate it.

Comment: you do know that a listbox can use scrollbars, do you? :)

Comment: @Pikoh i completely forgot that , thanks to remind me that, and yeah it is better way to do it

Comment: @Pikoh i will use your suggestion as an alternative option, but i would like to know if there is any way to use checkbox in dropdownlist, anyway thank you for your precious suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DropDownCheckBoxes-ASPNet-DropDownList-CheckBoxList-Server-control.aspx) but i haven't tried it. And you're welcome :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122650/discussion-between-kinjal-patel-and-pikoh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard HTML element do this, but you can build your own using asp.net as a new control if you are on asp.net forms, or you can write a custom HTML element and make it look like a drop down.

Also there are many plugins and libraries do exactly this such as:
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect
[jQuery multiselect drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753407/jquery-multiselect-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the multiple attribute?

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i want to use it in asp.net and i don't think so that _dropdownlist_  contain such property like that

Comment: use list box then <asp:ListBox runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" >

Comment: sure i m gonna use that as your and pikoh's suggestion, but also want to see dropdownlist option as an alternative.