# Creating checkboxes from drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I've tried to look up a working solution for my problem, but after days of research a couldn't fine one, and that's why i'm asking for your help.

Basically, what i would like to do is to have a drop down menu, with several year group options in it. So for example the drop down menu would have year 7, year 8 year 9 etc inside of it.

Once they select year 7, the system would create only one checkbox. For year 8 and 9 there should be two checkboxes created, because they can choose either one or two subjects.

If the drop down menu is not changed, there should be no checkboxes.

I hope these all make sense and you guys will be able to give me an answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A visualization of what your wanting to do would help. The second half of your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this then:

```js
var subjectMap = {
  'Year 7' : ['Maths'],
  'Year 8' : ['Maths', 'English'],
  'Year 9' : ['Maths', 'English', 'French'],
  'Year 10' : ['French', 'History', 'Geography']
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  for (var year in subjectMap) {
    $('#yearGroup').append($('<option>', {value:year, text:year}));
  }
  
  $('#yearGroup').change(function () {
    var selectedYear = $("#yearGroup option:selected").val();
    $("input:radio[name='subjects']").hide().attr('checked', false);
    $("input:radio[name='subjects']").each(function(){
      $("#label"+ $(this).val()).hide();
    });
    for (var availableSubject in subjectMap[selectedYear]) {
      $("#" + subjectMap[selectedYear][availableSubject]).show();
      $("#" + subjectMap[selectedYear][availableSubject]).each(function(){
        $("#label"+ $(this).val()).show();
      });
    } 
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='yearGroup'></select><br>

<label for="Maths" id="labelMaths">Maths</label><input type="radio" name="subjects" value="Maths" id="Maths">
<label for="English" id="labelEnglish">English</label><input type="radio" name="subjects" value="English" id="English">
<label for="French" id="labelFrench">French</label><input type="radio" name="subjects" value="French" id="French">
<label for="History" id="labelHistory">History</label><input type="radio" name="subjects" value="History" id="History">
<label for="Geography" id="labelGeography">Geography</label><input type="radio" name="subjects" value="Geography" id="Geography">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of [Google](https://www.google.ru/?q=jquery%20dropdown%20multiselect&#newwindow=1&q=jquery%20dropdown%20multiselect) answers, dozen [jQuery plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/multiselect/) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753407/jquery-multiselect-drop-down-menu) answers already asked and resolved about it. Why it's not acceptable for you or what exclusively you need?

Comment: There are loads of jQuery plugins i know but I specifically wanted to do it with javascript.